# How do I tell CKEditor 5 to use inline styling on the elements which it creates instead of them being class-based?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x, ckeditor5

I'm using CKEditor 5 on my website in order to allow users to generate PDF templates for their company.

My issues is, that once I take the data out of the ckEditor, every styled element has a class="CSS-Class-Here", which is problematic due to the fact that when I convert the HTML contents of the CKEditor to PDF, the PDF doesnt know any of these classes.

Is there any way to get CKEditor to save these classes as inline styles?

I know that its possible to create a plugin for a specific element for a specific style, but I want everything to act this way, not something specific.

Also, It's impossible to just inject the styles into the PDF itself, due to the fact that ckEditor keeps their styles in javascript functions and creates them on demand.

For example:
Yellow highlighted text comes out as:
`<mark class="" marker-yellow "">Random Text</mark>`

I would like it to come out as:
`<mark style="background: yellow">Random Text</mark>`

Meaning that the style that's present in the marker-yellow class should be applied inline directly to the element itself.

Comment: hi any solution yet?

Comment: No, sadly...I ended up switching over to CKEditor 4 which is far more superior in many aspects, as well as styling.

Comment: You are saying CKEditor 4 gives you the ability to export inline styles with the html? I ran into this same issue but trying to deal with emails instead of pdfs. Does the .getData() call return inline styles by default?

Comment: I have this same challenge.  I'm attempting to use the output of .getData() to send emails as well.  I have not yet found a way around this and would love a solution.

Comment: I added this as a feature request:  https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/8473